# How to use quadratic regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I am trying to learn how to fit a quadratic regression model. The dataset can be downloaded from:
https://filebin.net/ztr9har5nio7x78v

Let be "AdjSalePrice"  the target variable and "SqFtTotLiving", "SqFtLot", "Bathrooms", "Bedrooms", "BldgGrade" the predictor variables.

Imagine that "SqFtTotLiving" will be the variable that will have the degree 2. Be the python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import sklearn


houses = pd.read_csv("house_sales.csv", sep = '\t')#separador é tab

colunas = ["AdjSalePrice","SqFtTotLiving","SqFtLot","Bathrooms","Bedrooms","BldgGrade"]

houses1 = houses[colunas]


X = houses1.iloc[:,1:] ## 
y =  houses1.iloc[:,0] ##
```

How to fit a quadratic regression model using sklearn and statsmodels? I can only use linear regression ...

Answer (score 1):

First if you have a 1D array for X, do this:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
x = x.reshape((-1,1))
```

Result:

```
>>>x
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

Then this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
poly_variables = poly.fit_transform(x)

poly_var_train, poly_var_test, res_train, res_test = train_test_split(poly_variables, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 4)

regression = linear_model.LinearRegression()

model = regression.fit(poly_var_train, res_train)
testing_score = model.score(poly_var_test, res_test)
```

Comment: what is "results" inside train_test_split ?

Comment: @EdS, should be `y`, sorry. `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)` from the sklearn document. (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: :I got an error -> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=1.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: You can use numpy to reshape it. The sklearn require 2D array, even it is only 1D. For example, instead of `[1,2,3,4]`, you need `[[1], [2], [3], [4]]`.
Use this as sample: `B = np.reshape(A, (-1, 2))`, it will reshape A to a 2D.

Comment: np.shape(x) é (5647,). I dont know what to do!

Comment: Could you help me? I dont know: np.shape(x) é (5647,)

Comment: You mean `np.shape(x)`, and it return `(5647,)`? See answer, I just updated

Comment: I got an error running your code: "
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=1.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."